# Becoming a prudent Android developer. Is having multiple phones necessary?

Tags: android

Is having multiple phones of various screen sizes and model a must? Will it be more convenient, and would you recommend it to someone serious in developing for Android?

Comment: The emulator is a good start but the reality is that small differences by different manufactures across different devices won't be covered in the emulator.

Comment: you don't have to own every physical device, some manufacturers let you register for remote testing with their device pool

Answer (score 1):

There is no single way of developing an Android app. These are nice reads for multiple screens support.

- [Multiple screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [Supporting different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

For Android app development, you don't need to have multiple physical devices. Emulators would be enough. What I used to do is, testing it on multiple screen sizes and densities.

[image: These are the emulators I use for testing]

These are the emulators I use for testing. I think it's pretty much covering all the device screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it is quite helpful to run on various different real devices. I only have a couple real devices myself though, so I have used AWS Device Farm a few times. It can be helpful to determine layout based issues that you may have on other phones, and it allows you to run a bunch of tests simultaneously. I don't have the time to test everything manually on all of the different device sizes.

https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is helpful having a weak (out of memory errors, slower CPU, ...) and a powerful phone. It is also good to have a tablet because of the 4x3 display format.